# Merge User Accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-accounts

Can we get the [migrated answer account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34023/how-to-end-a-relationship-with-a-client-without-pissing-them-off) merged with the [new posters account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/12490/thesam18888)?